# array with custom object Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have class office, and want to have array of employees to it

```
class Office {
    var Employees: Array<Employee>
}
```

I also created a separated Employee.swift file, but the complier gives error of use of undeclared type "Employee" whats wrong here?

Comment: Have you created an `Employee` type?

Comment: Did you declare Employee in swift or in objective-c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare the class Employee like this

```
class Employee {

  var name : String
  var age : Int

  init(name: String, age : Int)
  {
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
  }
}
```

---

```
class Office {
    var employees = Array<Employee>()
}
```

to avoid confusion variable names should always begin with a lowercase letter, class names with an uppercase letter

Comment: `var employees = Array<Employee>()` is not the same as `var Employees: Array<Employee>` - and the latter *is not* wrong. The former declares an array of `Employee`, *and* initialises it to empty. The second declares an array, but doesn't initialise it.

Comment: I know, I wanted to avoid the `Class 'Office' has no initializers` error message ;-)

Comment: That's fair, but I'm worried that people would be confused into thinking that the error in the question is the syntax of `var Employees: Array<Employee>`, and that the solution is to change it to `var employees = Array<Employee>()`